# in Backbone, is it possible to tell fetch that it if it reads content that is content-type:'text/plain' to read it as JSON

Tags: backbone.js

I have a webserver that is sending back json files as 'text/plain'. I unfortunately can't adjust this. Can I tell a backbone fetch on a collection to read it as JSON even if it has this content/type? Like an emulateJSON for the response?

thx

Basically want to fix this:

[image]

Here's my backbone code that I'm having problems with (total backbone noob so I know there is most likely something wrong with how I'm handling this):

```
var MyItemList=Backbone.Collection.extend({url:'items.json', model:MyItem,
   // not sure if I need this?
   parse: function(response) {
    return response.results;
  }
});

var AppRouter=Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes:{'':'list','detail/:id':'detail'},
     list:function(){
     var itemList=new MyItemList();

     itemList.fetch({ dataType:'json',
                      error: function () {
                        console.log("error!!"); 
                      },
                      success: function () {
                         console.log("no error"); 
                      }
                   }).complete(function () {
                       console.log('done');
                       console.log('length1:' +  itemList.length);
                   });
    console.log('length2: '+ itemList.length);
}
```

my json:

[image]

**Remove parse method:**

[image]

**With Parse:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under the hood for the ajax requests.

So you need to use the `dataType: 'json'` options to specify how jQuery should treat the response when you are calling `fetch`:

```
yourCollection.fetch({
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: thx, that sounds like it should be right but my backbone code is still not working and giving me a length of 0. this is my first time using backbone so I've added my collection code above.

Comment: @timpone your backbone code seems fine, but how is a resposne text look like? Can you post an example response?

Comment: thx, I just posted a chrome screenshot of response. I think this is correct ... but obviously not sure. thx again

Comment: OK you don't need the your  `parse: function(response) {
    return response.results;
  }` remove it and it should work fine. You would only need this if your response wouldn't be a simple array but `{ results: [ {id:"11", name: "Jonathan"} ]`

Comment: thx, yeah, I was trying to parse because I saw it on a blog. If I take out parse on the collection, I get the undefined error above. Sorry, I'm sure total noob mistake here on my end.

Comment: I can only repro this error if `MyItem` is undefined when you are using in your collection as `model:MyItem`. So what is `MyItem` how is the definied and what its value before the `var MyItemList=Backbone.Collection.extend` call? Maybe your scripts files are not loading in order or you have definied your Model class after the collection in your source file... http://jsfiddle.net/CHX27/

Comment: thx, you are 100% correct, the code you provided works. I had a typo in another part. thx again

Comment: I was having the same problem with a pure text response. Setting `{dataType: 'text'}` was the solution. Thanks very much for pointing it out!